# cordova error when install fcm plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I got build conflict error while build the ionic app. It shows the below error.

Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
  Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
  :processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.148 secs

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com
>   .google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  (node:5008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely other plugins are specifying different of the Play Services library but Firebase is pulling in version `9.0.0` of the Google Services plugin which needs to align with the Play Services version.

You can try using [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) to align the versions:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=9.0.0
cordova platform rm android --nosave && cordova platform add android --nosave
```